# running error: unindent does not match any outer indentation level Jupiter Notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tqdm import tqdm

from __future1__ import div
from __future1__ import printf


class ConvertToNew(SuperModel):
   
    def __init__(self, name='r', loss_func='cross_entropy',
                 learning_rate=0.01, num_epochs=10, batch_size=10):
         self.loss_func = loss_func
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        
        SupervisedModel.__init__(self, name)

        
        self.num_epo = num_epochs1


File "<tokenize>", line 14
    self.learning_rate = learning_rate
    ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Comment: Yes, you will get this error message with that code. Please update your question with a question.

Comment: Thanks for comment quamrana but when i try to running this code i get this
File "<tokenize>", line 14
    self.learning_rate = learning_rate
    ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Answer (score 0):

It is because you gave extra space in line `self.loss_func = loss_func` that's why you're getting indentation error. Try the following code.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tqdm import tqdm

from __future1__ import div
from __future1__ import printf


class ConvertToNew(SuperModel):
   
    def __init__(self, name='r', loss_func='cross_entropy',
                 learning_rate=0.01, num_epochs=10, batch_size=10):
        self.loss_func = loss_func
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        
        SupervisedModel.__init__(self, name)

        
        self.num_epo = num_epochs1
```